# How to persist non-trivial fields in Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, weka, ebean

I am trying to persist complex objects using Ebeans in Play Framework (2.03). In particular, I've created a class that contains a field of type weka.classifier.Classifier (Weka is a popular machine learning library - see http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html). Classifier implements Serializeable so I hoped that I can get away with something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classifiers")
public class ClassifierData extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public Classifier classifier;
}
```

However, the Evolutions script suggests the following database structure:

```
create table classifiers (
   id  bigint auto_increment not null,
   constraint pk_classifiers primary key (id))
)
```

In other words, it ignores the field of type Classifier.

(The database is MySQL if it makes any difference)

What should I do to store complex serializeable objects using Ebean/Evolutions/PlayFramework?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using JPA for database access. You can store , see [Java EE5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html)

- User-defined serializable types
- byte[]
- Byte[]

It seems that Classifier type is not saved to database even though Classifier class implements java.io.Serializable. I think you should use byte[] for saved model and String for classifier type. You can use following methods to see how weka write and read models.

- weka.core.SerializationHelper.write
- weka.core.SerializationHelper.read

Store serialized object itself in database as byte[].

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classifiers")
public class ClassifierData extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public byte[] classifierSavedModel;
    public String classifierType
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Atilla. I hoped that I can do it in  way compatible with Evolutions (which regenerates the database structure according to the changes one makes in the Java bean's structure). Going with the custom serialization will mean that I have to switch it off to prevent overwriting the changes.